# Passing S3 loaction as an argument to the hadoop jar

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to pass the file location which is in Amazon S3 as an argument to my Hadoop jar.That file contains an XML file, where i need to parse that XML file in my driver class in map-reduce.So how can i pass that location? Where to specify the S3 credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run your MR job with s3n location. Upload your jar file and input to S3 and run it by `elastic-mapreduce` like below:

```
elastic-mapreduce --jar s3://mybucket/mycode.jar \
    --args "-D,mapred.reduce.tasks=0"
    --arg s3://mybucket/input \
    --arg s3://mybucket/output
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to set s3 credentials in configuration files such as `mapred-site.xml or core-site.xml` or you can pass below parameters using custom configuration file using -conf. Your `hadoop jar` command will look like `hadoop jar <jar_file_name> <class_name> -conf <custom_conf> <arguments>`

```
<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
<value>AWS-ID</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
<value>AWS-SECRET-KEY</value>
</property>
```